# invalid operands to binary expression ('std::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'const char *')

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, cheerp

When trying to compile my c++ code with Cheerp (using clang++), I get this output from my terminal:

```
example.cpp:102:9: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::ostream'
      (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'const char *')
    out << "(" << loc.x << ", " << loc.y << ")";
    ~~~ ^  ~~~
```

Here is my command to the terminal:

```
/opt/cheerp/bin/clang++ -target cheerp example.cpp -o example.js
```

And Here is the code it has trouble with:

```
static std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream & out, const CornerLoc &loc)
{
    out << "(" << loc.x << ", " << loc.y << ")";
    if (loc.type == kCorner)
        out<<"-corner";
    if (loc.type == kCornerNorthWest)
        out<<"-cornerNW";
    if (loc.type == kCornerNorthEast)
        out<<"-cornerNE";
    if (loc.type == kCornerSouthWest)
        out<<"-cornerSW";
    if (loc.type == kCornerSouthEast)
        out<<"-cornerSE";
    return out;
}
```

Comment: I guess your standard library headers are corrupted.

Comment: @Lingxi how can I fix them?

Comment: Just a guess. I'm not sure. Try compile the code in question on an online compiler (e.g., [Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox)) and see whether the problem remains.

Comment: To whoever is reviewing this: It has all the details it needs. One would really not expect `ostream << cstr` to not work and this is literally how this issue presents itself. What other information do you want? A memory dump? It's exactly what this question needs to be to help others with the same issue.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

FIXED:: I just forgot to `#include <iostream>`

Comment: Actually it might be just `#include <ostream>`